# Reduce complexity and time consuming deleting duplicates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a dataframe from a bigger one like this:

[image]

As you can see in "tokens" columns I have in each row a list of tokens i.e.:

```
['@vesteve3', '@manubenas', '@ccoo_rm', '@desobediencia_', '@ccoo', '@emparempar', '(', 'buen', 'ánimo', 'para', 'esta', 'primavera', 'que', 'iniciamos', ')', '.']
```

So now I would like to create a new dataframe from that column to store each individual token with number of times it appears, like this:

[image]

To create this dataframe I used the following code:

```
def get_dictionary(input: pd.Series)->pd.DataFrame:
  results_final = pd.DataFrame(columns=['tokens', 'count'])
  results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['tokens'])
  
  for i in range(len(input)):
    tokens_row = input.iloc[i]
    df_local = pd.DataFrame(tokens_row, columns= ['tokens'])
    results =  results.append(df_local, ignore_index = True)

  dups_tokens = results.pivot_table(columns=['tokens'], aggfunc='size')
  results_final['tokens'] = dups_tokens.index.tolist()
  results_final['count'] = dups_tokens.values
  
  return results_final
```

As my original dataframe has 181504 rows and each list of tokens can have 144 tokens as maximum, my code is very time consuming.

So I would like to know if there is a simpler way to do it like built-in-functions in pandas because I need to run this function several times,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post text instead of images to make it easier to reproduce your problem

Comment: I added first row as example, thanks

Comment: Do `df.drop_duplicates` and `df.unique` not work for you?